# Generating random number inside a paralleled loop (openmp)

Tags: c++, openmp

What is the most fast and safe way of generating random numbers inside a pararelled loop? I did as below but I'm not sure if it is correct or not:

```
using namespace std;
std::minstd_rand gen(std::random_device{}());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unirnd(0, 1);
int main(){
double eta=something;
double x[N];
//initializing x[] 
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{
double z= unirnd(gen) * eta;
x[i] = some function of x[i] and z
}
}
```

To compile the code, I use `g++ -fopenmp -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -g code.cpp -o a.out`

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;` Also there are no openmp pragmas in your code. Code posted to Code Review should be compilable, yours clearly isn't.

Comment: If you don't know whether it's correct, it probably isn't ready for review.  If you think it is correct, I suggest you [edit] to add your unit-tests, and we can help determine what you've overlooked.

Comment: For crying out loud, use some whitespace next time. It's free.

Comment: I'll echo @TobySpeight here: if it works, we can help. If it doesn't, we won't. That's the rules, see the [help/on-topic]. If you don't know whether it works, how should we know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating good random numbers is a hard problem, and generating parallel random numbers is harder. (Consider that you don't want to replicate the same sequence in different threads). You should use a library which provides a parallel random number generator (such as [Intel MKL [now free for anyone]](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/free-mkl)). It has an implementation of the generator described in [Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/38bc/7fc62136ec779d91b86b6e960a06d67b4a97.pdf) which may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to give each thread its own RNG seeded (and sometimes reseeded) by a master RNG in a thread-safe manner.